# Does the New Google Analytics Code Support Display Advertising?

Tags: google-analytics

We're trying to add the display advertising line from the example here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en&utm_id=ad to our new Analytics code, but the example seems to be using the older code.

Does anybody know how to properly add the Display Ad code where it will work?

This is how we're currently doing it and it doesn't seem to be reporting:

```
<!-- Start Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'site.com');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/Step1');
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Answer (score 3):

The New Google Analytics (Universal Analytics) doesn't currently support Display Advertising. This is straight from the [Universal Analytics Upgrade Center](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/):

> Universal Analytics does not currently support the the dc.js JavaScript and related features (Remarketing, Google Display Network Impression Reporting, DoubleClick Campaign Manager Integration, and the Google Analytics Demographics and Interests Reports). If you use any of these features, upgrade to Universal Analytics after dc.js is supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX', 'example.com');
    **ga('require', 'displayfeatures');**
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

The bolded line is what Google recommended to use for Display Ads tracking with the new Universal Analytics tracking code.